# Searching for matches in a non-cmdlet's output

Tags: powershell, pipelining

I'm evidently misunderstanding something about PowerShell's piping (I'm quite new to the language).

I'm trying to "grep" for a certain match in the help menu of `ssh-keygen`. For a simple example, I'm trying to find every line that contains a "C" (I don't care about case at the moment). I tried:

```
ssh-keygen /? | Select-String "C"
```

The problem is, `ssh-keygen` appears to be attempting to consume the entire rest of the command, since I get this output:

```
PS C:\Users\user\tests> ssh-keygen /? | Select-String "C"
Too many arguments.
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile] [-m format]
. . .
```

If, however, I try to do a similar operation on a (python script) file that I read in, it works as I'd expect:

```
PS C:\Users\user\tests> Get-ChildItem .\produce_image.py | Select-String "def"

produce_image.py:12:def draw_mandelbrot_with(canvas_dimensions: Tuple[int, int],
produce_image.py:38:def par_iterate_mandelbrot_with(canvas_dimensions: Tuple[int, int],
. . .
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that `ssh-keygen` is a standalone executable, whereas `Get-ChildItem` is a cmdlet, and they're writing to different streams? Or something like that?

I'd just like to know how to search through the output of non-cmdlets using PowerShell. Any help here would be appreciated. I'm using PowerShell 7 in case that's at all relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `ssh-keygen /?` issues its output to `stderr` (stream 2),
while the pipe (`|`) is passing through only `stdout` (stream 1).

You should rather use:

```
ssh-keygen.exe /? 2>&1 | Select-String "C"
```

The `2>&1` will redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so it can be passed on
to the following command.

Comment: It never even occurred to me that it would be printing to the stderr. I expected this to be some PowerShell specific issue. Thank you.